# correct usage of reference in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Here is my usage:

```cpp
void fun_out(int& mkol){
  mkol = 3;
}

class refTest{


public:
  int pol_as;

  refTest(int& poul):
    pol_as(poul){}

  void fun1(){
    fun_out(pol_as);
  }
};

int main(){

     int asl = 46;
     refTest testcase(asl);     // testcase.pol_as = 46

     testcase.fun1();           // testcase.pol_as = 3
     printf("testcase.pol_as: %d\n", testcase.pol_as);


}
```

I need to change `asl` to the value in `fun_out`, i.e. 3 in this case; however, this code cannot do it. Only `testcase.pol_as` is modified from 46 to 3. Do we have a method that can change the int(`asl`) or a pointer value(`int* asl_ptr`)  outside a class w.r.t. the result of a function (`fun1`) within this class?

Comment: If you want `pol_as` to be a reference to `asl`, then declare it as such like `int& pol_as`. Also `fun_out(a)` should change the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to change asl to the value in fun_out

Currently you're storing a copy of `asl` into the data member `pol_as`. This means that when you call `fun_out` from inside `fun1` it will only effect that copy. So to achieve the desired effect you can either make the data member `pol_as` as an *lvalue reference to `int`* or you can directly call `fun_out` passing `asl` as shown below:

**Method 1**

```
class refTest{

private:
//----v---------->lvalue reference 
  int &pol_as;
public:
  refTest(int& poul):
    pol_as(poul){}

  void fun1(){
    fun_out(pol_as);
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OXRmwEvNU)

**Method 2**

Or directly call `fun_out` passing `asl`.

```
int main(){

     int asl = 46;
     
     fun_out(asl);//directly pass asl
     std::cout<<"asl: "<<asl;

}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/osvXvmFYN)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store a reference in normal data variable. You need to make `pol_as` a reference than your code will run fine.